# What is the best way to arrange navigation in Android compose if the destination screens are calculated at runtime?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

What is the best way to arrange navigation in Android if the destination screens are calculated at runtime? Can use this pattern, written by GPT? :

When the destination screens are calculated at runtime, we need to use the NavController API provided by the Android Jetpack Navigation component to handle navigation dynamically.

To organize navigation in Android Compose, we can do the following:

1. In the destination screens calculate logic, we need to pass the destination ID to the NavController object, and navigate to the screen using the NavController's navigate method.
2. We can define a navController object in the composable that manages the Navigation. Then pass this navController object to children composables and use it to navigate to the destination screens.

Here is an example code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NavigationScreen() {
    // Create a NavController object
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    // Define a variable to store the destination Id
    var destinationId by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // Navigate to the destination screen based on destinationId
    LaunchedEffect(destinationId) {
        if (destinationId != 0) {
            navController.navigate(destinationId)
        }
    }

    // Create a composable that can calculate the destination Id based on business logic
    val calculateDestinationId: (String) -> Int = { input: String ->
        // Calculation logic here
        val result = /* Calculation results */;
        result
    }

    // Render the navigation composable
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "main"
    ) {
        composable("main") {
            // Main screen composable
            MainScreen(
                calculateDestinationId = calculateDestinationId,
                navigateToDestination = { destinationId ->
                    // Navigate to the destination screen
                    this.destinationId = destinationId
                }
            )
        }
        composable(/* Add other composable destination screens here */)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    calculateDestinationId: (String) -> Int,
    navigateToDestination: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    // Define a variable to store the input value
    var input by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column {
        // Render the input field
        TextField(
            value = input,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                input = value
            }
        )

        // Render the button to navigate to the destination screen
        Button(
            onClick = {
                // Calculate the destination Id based on the input value
                val destinationId = calculateDestinationId(input)

                // Navigate to the destination screen
                navigateToDestination(destinationId)
            }
        ) {
            Text("Navigate")
        }
    }
}
```

In this example code, we define a `NavigationScreen` composable that manages the navigation. Inside the `NavigationScreen`, we define a `NavController` object and create a `NavHost` composable that handles the navigation.

We pass the `calculateDestinationId` and `navigateToDestination` functions to the `MainScreen` composable as parameters. Inside the `MainScreen`, we render an input field and a button. When the button is clicked, we call the `calculateDestinationId` function to calculate the destination Id based on the input value. Then, we call the `navigateToDestination` function to navigate to the destination screen.

The `NavigationScreen` composable uses a `LaunchedEffect` to navigate to the destination screen when the `destinationId` variable changes. This ensures that the navigation happens outside of the main composition cycle to avoid recomposition issues.